# Is it possible to disable the auto update on timepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im using  angular-ui-bootstrap for user to enter a date, but this date is being inserted with the current date and i would like to remove this functionality, is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

EDIT1:

```
<uib-timepicker ng-model="dTime" hour-step="1" minute-step="1" show-meridian="false" show-spinners="false" ng-disabled="!editable"></uib-timepicker>
```

EDIT2:

[image]

After i enter values on the seconds input zone, hours and minute are filled automatically.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "inserted with the current date"... inserted where? The timepicker as the init value? The return value from the timepicker? Somewhere else entirely?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: looks like it is a known issue and you can look to the workaround [there](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1114)

Comment: @Nikolay was finally able to resolve the issue by adapting one of the workaround display in that thread. I needed to updated the variable within the scope with the input from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a older version of this functionality so it might not apply to everyone.
On the updateTemplate function I did the following changes with the intent of not using the current time having as little impact as possible on the other functionalities;

```
var hours = selected.getHours(),
          minutes = selected.getMinutes(),
          //seconds = selected.getSeconds();
          seconds;
          if(selected.getSeconds() != createdAtStart.getSeconds()){
            seconds = selected.getSeconds();
          }else{
            seconds = 0;
            selected.setSeconds(0);
          }
```

I feel that this is more of a hack than a possible change that should be implemented but maybe this will help others.